# Set column value to the value of the next row if a condition is true for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where I want to overwrite the value of another column with the value in the next row, if a condition is true for a different column.  For example, my data looks like this:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | False |
| 40 | True |
| 50 | False |

And I want the value in `col1` where where `col2 == True` to be set to the value in `col1` of the row following, like so:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | False |
| 50 | True |
| 50 | False |

I've tried `df.loc[df.col2 == True, 'col1'] = df.col1.shift()`, which doesn't work.  I suspect this has to do with the `shift()` function but I'm not sure how to overcome this without resorting to some kind of custom `apply` function.

Comment: add a `peroids=-1` argument in `shift()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give shift(-1) if you want the next row.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[30,40,50],
                   'col2':[False,True,False]})
print (df)
df.loc[df['col2'],'col1'] = df['col1'].shift(-1)
print (df)
```

Here's the output:

Before:

```
   col1   col2
0    30  False
1    40   True
2    50  False
```

After:

```
   col1   col2
0  30.0  False
1  50.0   True
2  50.0  False
```